# C# Read from file to string array

Tags: c#

I'd like to be able to read numbers from a text file and store them in a string array with the intention of showing them in a listBox.

Here is code:

```
string[] filePath = @"C:Site\Project3\Sales.txt";

foreach (string val in filePath)
{
    listBoxValues.Items.Add(val.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines()` ... should do the work and then parse each to number and add to list

Comment: Are they separated by new lines or commas or smiley faces?

Comment: @Rahul could you give me an example of what parse the number would look like? And where to put the `File.ReadAllLines()`? Thanks!

Comment: @TheGeneral, they are separated by lines haha

Comment: @TheDude - Why "haha"?

Comment: See if you understand [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3)

Comment: @Enigmativity because he asked if they were separated by smiley faces. I assumed he was joking?

Comment: @Adriani6 ok I will keep that in mind next time thanks. I updated the question with how the numbers are separated.

Comment: @TheDude - Fair enough. I missed that. I was a bit confused.

Comment: I was going to write an answer with `parse`, but the comments are all you need really, you just need `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: @TheGeneral ok thank you. I will try and see if I can figure out how/where to incorporate `File.ReadAllLines()`

Comment: You can use addrange to add an array to listbox in one shot too

Comment: Just wanted to mention this because the answers don't talk about error handling: Remember that [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) throws exceptions, check the MSDN article for more information, this is probably test code / throwaway code but whatever you do, please don't use that method for anything important or long term without having an exception handling strategy, and `File.Exists` won't help, be prepared for that method to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

you don't need to `parse` per-se, the following should work if you only want to read from the file into a list box without validating the numbers

```
listBoxValues.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("soemFile.txt"));
```

**Original**

Its as simple as,

```
listBoxValues.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("soemFile.txt")
                                 .Select(int.Parse)
                                 .ToList());
```

**Note** : this doesn't check empty lines

[File.ReadAllLines Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array,
>   and then closes the file.

[Enumerable.Select Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Int32.Parse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
public List<string> ToList(string filePath)
{
    // Identifiers used are:
    var valueList = List<string>();
    var fileStream = new StreamReader(filePath);
    string line;

    // Read the file line by line
    while ((line = fileStream.readLine()) != null)
    {
       // Split the line by the deliminator (the line is a single value)
       valueList.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Or you could try something like this also to be more general:

```
public List<string> ToList(string filePath, char deliminator=',')
{
    // Identifiers used are:
    var valueList = List<string>();
    var fileStream = new StreamReader(filePath);
    string line;

    // Read the file line by line
    while ((line = fileStream.readLine()) != null)
    {
       // Split the line by the deliminator
       var splitLine = line.Split(deliminator);
       foreach (string value in splitLine) 
       {
          valueList.Add(value);
       }
    }
}
```

you can then use this to fill your list box. This is not the most efficient way but it should work for your case and you can build on it if needed.

Comment: Ok I will give this a shot if I cannot get the `File.ReadAllLines()` to work. Thank you